# Bone IK Constraints - Bone Transformation Data

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I create animations on Blender and export the keyframes using custom plugin to be used in others appliances.
In order to run the animation on other programs, the transformation data recorded on the keyframe are need (see Picture 1)
[image: Picture 1]

The point is, when I'm using Bone Constraint's Inverse Kinematics, the bones influenced by it doesn't have any data transform.

For example, in this model sample, I used basic IK constraints scheme to control the legs. When I position the root bone or the IK bone (Picture 2; the main one located in the hips) the bone transform data is recorded, but for the leg bones not. However the leg bones was been deformed (picture 3). Same occur for the arm bones.

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picure 3]

Plus, when I pose the head bone (upper top bone), both data transformation for head and spine are added (picture 4 and 5). Note that there's no IK Bone Contrain added to this bone.

[image: Picture 4]
[image: Picure 5]

Without this information, these bones won't be animated when I export the keyframes

Is there any sub-routine to surpass this?

Thank you!

Comment: Blender's constraints are like modifiers-- dynamically calculated on the basis of the existing transforms.  They do not change the transforms themselves.  If you want the transforms post-constraint, you can consider baking visual keyframes with the "bake action" operation.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan I will check this operation! Regards